# how to get value in array from individual query

Tags: php, mysql

i have a

```
Book ID Array

    Array
    (
        [0] => 61
        [1] => 72
        [2] => 78
        [3] => 100
        [4] => 102
    )
```

*now from another table `table_bookPrice` where price filed is given
i want that select all price from table_bookPrice where book id is in given array (book ID Array) and if price is not mentioned in `table_bookPrice` field then it would be automatic 500*

what will be exact query

so the array i got is like this

```
Book Price Array

    Array
    (
        [0] => 150
        [1] => 100
        [2] => 500 ( not mentioned in table, so it is 500)
        [3] => 300
        [4] => 200
    )
```

Comment: If the price is not mentioned, is the field `null` or is there no row in the `table_bookPrice` for this book?

Comment: Are you updating the table if a price does not exist or just making an array?

Comment: just making an array of boook price, not updating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am at work so could not test or compile it, but I hope my logic is understandable.

Not sure if this will work but something along these lines

```
$book_price_array = array(); //contents to be added.

// loop through the array an examine its price by querying your table.
foreach ($book_id_array as $key => $value) {
   $price = mysql_query("SELECT price FROM table_bookPrice 
                                     WHERE book_id = {$value}");
   // there is a price, set the price.
   if ($price > 0 && $price != NULL)  $book_price_array[$key] = $price;

   // there is no price, set the default price
   else  $book_price_array[$key] = 500; 
}
```

Comment: Why did you comment out part of your query in the else clause?  Clearly you *didn't* have time to test this...

Comment: Clearly you *didn't* read what I had put above? I commented it out because he did not want to update the table with a new value, just his array.

Comment: it results a new array 
where value of array  is book id if row exist in table_bookPrice and if row does not exist then it's value is 500;

i need that if row exist then value should be price not the book id($value)

and one more thing

`$book_price_array = new array();` gives error  
new keyword is not used in php( as i know)

Comment: I updated my answer, I removed the `new` keyword and I added a variable `$price` that is set to the price of the book_id, if it exists it is added to the `$book_price_array`. Also I added to see if the value `NULL` was returned from the MySQL query

Comment: Thank You Sir, 
Now one little quetion,
if i want array which key is book id and value is book price ,then how it is possible in above query

another method i array_combine() ( i know)

Comment: i said not using array_combine() in last line on my comment, anyways i got the answer myself 
we  can use
`$book_price_array[$value]` instead of `$book_price_array[$key]`

Comment: Ah, didn't see that but I'm glad you figured it out

Answer (score 0):

Here's the test database I built for your problem:

```
mysql> select  * from table_bookPrice;
+----+-------+--------+
| id | price | bookid |
+----+-------+--------+
|  1 |   150 |     61 |
|  2 |   100 |     72 |
|  3 |   300 |    100 |
|  4 |   200 |    102 |
+----+-------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here's the PHP code:

```
<?php

$books=array(61,72,78,100,102);

// establish an assoc array of bookid => default_price
$prices=array();
foreach($books as $bookid){
    $prices["$bookid"]=500;
}

// build query to select all prices stored in database
$bookids=implode(', ',$books);
mysql_connect('localhost','aj','nothing') or die('unable to connect!');
mysql_select_db('books') or die('unable to select db!');
$stmt="SELECT bp.bookid, bp.price FROM table_bookPrice bp WHERE bp.bookid IN ($bookids)";
$res=mysql_query($stmt);
while( ($rec= mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) ){
    $idstr=(string)$rec['bookid'];
    $prices[$idstr]=$rec['price'];
}

print_r($prices);

?>
```

This outputs:

```
Array
(
    [61] => 150
    [72] => 100
    [78] => 500
    [100] => 300
    [102] => 200
)
```

Comment: `but if there is no row in table_bookPrice corresponding book id then it should be 500 `,then what will be query

Comment: @I Like PHP right you are...changed my answer.  give it a try now.

Comment: but there is no table of table_books , there is just an array of table_book which contain id of books
(that array comes from some method) so it is no possible to join one array and one table

Comment: @I Like PHP...ah, ok.  changed my answer again.  hope it works for you this way now.