# comparing values of two arrays in php

Tags: php, mysql, comparison

i have two arrays which keys are book id( 61, 78 ,...etc)

```
(1) book_width
     (
        [61] => 8.3
        [72] => 8286.1
        [78] => 6.4
        [100] => 8407.0
        [102] => 0.7
     )
```

---

```
(2) book_height
   (
    [61] => 9.00
    [72] => 150
    [78] => 8.00
    [100] => 150
    [102] => 3.00
  )
```

now i want an array which contain those books id's which their height is greater than or equal to their width

means i need an  array mention below

```
(2) book_dimension
       (     
 /*book id*/ [78] => 8.00 //along their height or width(anyone)
             [102] => 3.00
      )



 or only book id in a new array
    (2) book_dimension
           (     
            [0] => 78
            [1] => 102
      )
```

Comment: Would book_dimension also contain `[61] => 9.00`?

Comment: no!
 i need a fresh array which contain only book id( best for me)

or any array which key is book id and value can be height or width( value is useless for me)

Comment: Then I am lost, because `$book_height[61] > $book_width[61]`, isn't that what you want? Where their height is >= their width? Could you clarify further?

Comment: Considering your last question ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155843/how-to-get-value-in-array-from-individual-query ) can't this be done on the database level (i.e. with the appropriate sql query)?

Comment: i want only book id   and 

 i know it is not possible to get single array which contain book id
thats why  i want array along with book width or book height

Comment: @ VolkerK how can we done on database level , will u plz elaborate this, i m not so strong in MySQL

Comment: If we knew more about your database we could help you further.

Comment: Yep, we definitely need more info about what you're actually doing and what your database looks like. That might also improve the answers to your previous question.

Comment: I would definately go with a MySQL solution, if that is an option. Good call by these fellas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this should do it:

```
function compare_dimensions( $width, $height )
{
 return $height < $width;
}

$result = array_uintersect_assoc( $array_width, $array_height, 'compare_dimensions' );

var_dump( $result );
```

**EDIT:**
Oops: Comparing should be the other way around. (changed >= to < )

documentation: http://docs.php.net/array_uintersect_assoc

Comment: nice, I didn't know about the `callback $data_compare_func ` parameter of array\_uintersect\_assoc().

Comment: Honoustly: me neither ;-) I just like figuring out these kinds of puzzle questions. :-D

Comment: Very similar to `usort`, I like the flexibility of PHP where you can supply functions in args.

Comment: Definately. As of PHP 5.3 you can even supply lambda functions and closures as arguments to these kinds of functions I believe.

Answer (score 1):

This has not been tested or compiled, I am *still* at work from your previous question.

I added the two approaches you could take, depending on the type of array to desire.

```
$book_dimension = array(); //contents to be added

foreach($book_height as $heightKey => $heightValue) {
      foreach($book_width as $widthKey => $widthValue) {
          // if height is greater than or equal to width
        if ($heightValue >= $widthValue) {

          // would return: $book_dimension[78] => "8.00"
          $book_dimension[$heightKey] = $heightValue;

          // or this approach, which will return: $book_dimension[0] => 78
          $book_dimension[] = $heightKey;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, i haven't tested it:

```
<?php

$book_width = array( 61 => 8.3,72 => 8286.1,78 => 6.4,100 => 8407.0,102 => 0.7);
$book_height = array(61 => 9.00, 72 => 150, 78 => 8.00, 100 => 150, 102 => 3.00);
$result = array();
foreach($book_height as $k => $v)
{
    if($v >= $book_width[$k])
    {
       $result[$k] = max($book_width[$k], $v);
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

p.s. Changed the code to conform the height condition. I tested it.

Comment: not doing anything
return blank array.
where is the condition dear???
see my question again please

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you really have to do this in php. You currently have two separate arrays, maybe you can do something about that and keep the data together (so that each element of the array describes one element/book).

```
$w = array(61 => 8.3, 72 => 8286.1, 78 => 6.4, 100 => 8407.0, 102 => 0.7);
$h = array(61 => 9.00,  72 => 150, 78 => 8.00,  100 => 150, 102 => 3.00);
$dimensions = array();
foreach($w as $key=>$width) {
  $dimensions[$key] = array('width'=>$width, 'height'=>$h[$key]);
}
```

Now having only one array you can use [array_filter()](http://docs.php.net/array_filter) to filter out all elements you do not want.

e.g. with php 5.3:

```
$result = array_filter($dimensions, function($x) { return $x['height']>=$x['width']; });
print_r($result);
```

in previous versions (that do not support this type of anonymous functions):

```
function heightGreateOrEqualWidth($x) {
  return $x['height']>=$x['width'];
}
$result = array_filter($dimensions, 'heightGreateOrEqualWidth');
print_r($result);
```